# Cron Bash - select data from two MySQL tables & export to CSV

Tags: mysql, bash, cron, export-to-csv

I am really bad at creating MySQL queries and need some help. I need to create a bash file to be triggered by a cron job once a week - that queries two tables, grabbing data where the user IDs match in both tables, and adding the select data to a CSV export file. I would like the CSV to be comma separated. Right now the best I can get it tab separated.

My issue in getting this query to run is my syntax (which I know is wrong as I have simply stolen snippets from various articles online). I did get each DB query to work separately (grabbing from one table with one query and another table with another query). Now I need to combine them to grab only the data I need.

Here's my current (non working) query:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database=xxxx_DBNAME --execute='SELECT `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id`, `xxxx_videotraining_user.training_title`, `xxxx_videotraining_user.status`, `xxxx_users.id`, `xxxx_users.name`, `xxxx_users.user_employer`, `xxxx_users.user_ss_number` WHERE `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id` = `xxxx_users.id` AND `xxxx_videotraining_user.status` = "Completed" AND `xxxx_users.user_ss_number` > "1" ORDER BY `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id` LIMIT 0, 10000 AND ' -C > /home/xxxx/subs/vtc/DB_EXPORTS/xxxx_videotraining_completed.csv
```

---

I think you can see what I am trying to accomplish here - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think this is specific to `cron`? Your problem is just with formulating the query, the fact that you're running it from cron is incidental.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no CLI option to create a CSV file. You can do it with the `INTO OUTFILE` clause in the `SELECT` statement, but then the MySQL server needs to have write permission to the file.

Answer (score 1):

It also looks like you're missing your FROM clause, have an trailing AND clause (as noted in other answers), and are quoting things incorrectly. This looks to be your original query:

```
SELECT `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id`, 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user.training_title`, 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user.status`, 
       `xxxx_users.id`, 
       `xxxx_users.name`, 
       `xxxx_users.user_employer`, 
       `xxxx_users.user_ss_number` 
 WHERE `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id` = `xxxx_users.id` AND 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user.status` = "Completed" AND 
       `xxxx_users.user_ss_number` > "1" 
ORDER BY `xxxx_videotraining_user.user_id` 
LIMIT 0, 10000 AND
```

I think you want to add the FROM clause, quote the table and field separately, and remove the trailing AND, to get something like:

```
    SELECT `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`user_id`, 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`training_title`, 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`status`, 
       `xxxx_users`.`id`, 
       `xxxx_users`.`name`, 
       `xxxx_users`.`user_employer`, 
       `xxxx_users`.`user_ss_number` 
  FROM `xxxx_users`,
       `xxxx_videotraining_user`
 WHERE `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`user_id` = `xxxx_users`.`id` AND 
       `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`status` = "Completed" AND 
       `xxxx_users`.`user_ss_number` > "1" 
ORDER BY `xxxx_videotraining_user`.`user_id` 
LIMIT 0, 10000
```

There are other things that could be done to shorten the size of the query and make it a bit cleaner, but that should get it functional.

One thing I know that helps me when dealing with long queries is to format them like this, with the main clauses separated out so you can see the different sections of the query.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think AND shouldn't be here:

```
LIMIT 0, 10000 AND
```